# Linq updating two tables I need Autoid value

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am doing some activity that will update two tables. One of the tables have an autoid which I need inserted in the other table. The field that stores the autoid value is used a like a foreign key to different tables depending on context.

When updating I face the problem that the autoinc Id does not have a value until its saved.

i have thought of having separate datacontexts for the two tables doing submit on one before the other but the I guess it will be very slow submitting for each row.

What are my options here, I guess I cannot have the foreign key to multiple tables as that would solve the problem ??

Martin

Comment: Can you post the tables structure?, it sound  to me like some foreign keys relations will solve the problem.

Comment: The two tables both have an Autoinc ID field which is a primary key.

The ref field I use as a joining field cannot be a normal foreign key as it should be able to point to different tables id in the next row. I just have two fields one tells which table the ref should be lika a foregn key to .

Comment: Well i think there is no other way to do it, you will have to commit the changes and then get the auto-generated ID.

Comment: Or have as many foreign keys as I have tables to reference which is probably the best anyway